# Request to local host using Electron

Tags: javascript, django, http, get, electron

How do I go about making a HTTP GET request to localhost using electron? I have a database that was created using Django and I just need to get information from an API that holds the information from this database? I am also using WebStorm as an IDE.
Thanks for the help !

Comment: Make sure you understand what it's explained in Django tutorial - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/. Then you can use request library to perform the request https://github.com/request/request

Answer (score 0):

In your html page, you pass the onClick event handler to a button like so:
`<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>`.

In the render process, do something like this to handle that onClick event:

```
   document.addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
    // do something
   }, false);
```

You will most likely want to use AJAX/xhr in place of where "do something" is in the code. Look at the MDN documentation for [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started), the [jquery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) library, and [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) links for examples and explanations.